# Scrapy CSRF cookies not accepted and results in a 302 Redirect

Tags: python, scrapy, session-cookies, csrf

I'm new to programming in general so I hope this isn't a stupid question. I've google'd and spent the last 4 hours trying to figure this out but couldn't so would really appreciate advice/steps I should try to resolve this problem. Thank you!

Here's what I have so far for the spiders:
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from tutorial.items import TutorialItem
    from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'pinterest'
    start_urls = ['https://www.pinterest.com/login/']

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username_or_email': '...', 'password': '...'},
                    callback=self.after_login, dont_filter = True)

    def after_login(self, response):
        print response.url
```

From what I understand, Scrapy handles the cookies automatically and therefore the CSRF tokens passed. I set COOKIES_ENABLED and COOKIES_DEBUG to True in my settings:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.cookies.CookiesMiddleware':     
700,}
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36"
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
```

Here's the output from the debugging:

```
2013-09-27 11:11:42-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-09-27 11:11:43-0700 [pinterest] DEBUG: Received cookies from: <200 https://
www.pinterest.com/login/>
        Set-Cookie: csrftoken=1FBJIzKqxH7XQ5tdXNtUIDHEJsL1210K; Domain=.pinteres
t.com; expires=Fri, 26-Sep-2014 18:11:46 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
        Set-Cookie: _pinterest_sess="eJwr9UotN47SN0rUjzJ3ciwo109N8UixNPM1znK0tY8
vycxNtfUN8TXxdfEt9wsJLfdLt7VVK04tLs5MsfXMyjb0c/c0AIpX+Ia4ZfpmBeX4uqSbRFYlG0SFuFb
4ZjlWRLkHGkZWuRp6AvUBAEY1IrA="; Domain=.pinterest.com; expires=Mon, 22-Sep-2014
18:11:46 GMT; Max-Age=31103999; Path=/
2013-09-27 11:11:43-0700 [pinterest] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.pinte
rest.com/login/> (referer: None)
2013-09-27 11:11:43-0700 [pinterest] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <POST https://ww
w.pinterest.com/login/>
        Cookie: csrftoken=1FBJIzKqxH7XQ5tdXNtUIDHEJsL1210K; _pinterest_sess="eJw
r9UotN47SN0rUjzJ3ciwo109N8UixNPM1znK0tY8vycxNtfUN8TXxdfEt9wsJLfdLt7VVK04tLs5MsfX
Myjb0c/c0AIpX+Ia4ZfpmBeX4uqSbRFYlG0SFuFb4ZjlWRLkHGkZWuRp6AvUBAEY1IrA="
2013-09-27 11:11:43-0700 [pinterest] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www
.pinterest.com/csrf_error/> from <POST https://www.pinterest.com/login/>
2013-09-27 11:11:43-0700 [pinterest] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: <GET http://www.
pinterest.com/csrf_error/>
        Cookie: csrftoken=1FBJIzKqxH7XQ5tdXNtUIDHEJsL1210K; _pinterest_sess="eJw
r9UotN47SN0rUjzJ3ciwo109N8UixNPM1znK0tY8vycxNtfUN8TXxdfEt9wsJLfdLt7VVK04tLs5MsfX
Myjb0c/c0AIpX+Ia4ZfpmBeX4uqSbRFYlG0SFuFb4ZjlWRLkHGkZWuRp6AvUBAEY1IrA="
2013-09-27 11:11:44-0700 [pinterest] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.pinter
est.com/csrf_error/> (referer: https://www.pinterest.com/login/)
http://www.pinterest.com/csrf_error/
```

The problem is that after the cookie is set and sent to the login page, I still get a CSRF error and get redirected. Am I doing something wrong that I can't simulate the login process as with a browser? I've tried setting the User Agent as an iPhone and got code 200 and no redirect but the response.url shows "https://www.pinterest.com/login/?next=/login/" so it's still not logging in properly.

Really appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the non-mobile login page uses XHR requests to perform the login. You could attempt to dig into the XHR requests and maybe the javascript code to see what you have to do in order to reproduce the request in scrapy.

But, as you pointed out, there is a mobile login page which is enabled by changing the user agent.

Your problem with the latter approach is that the field for the email is `email` instead of `username_or_email`.

This is the spider with the minor changes:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'pinterest'
    start_urls = ['https://www.pinterest.com/login/']
    # you can set the user agent either in the settings or the spider
    user_agent = ('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) '
                  'AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 '
                  'Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3')

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {'email': 'XXX@xxx', 'password': 'xxx'}
        # no need for dont_filter
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=data, callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        print response.url
```

The output:

```
$ scrapy runspider pinterest.py
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [pinterest] INFO: Spider opened
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [pinterest] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-09-28 19:16:58-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-09-28 19:17:01-0400 [pinterest] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.pinterest.com/login/> (referer: None)
2013-09-28 19:17:09-0400 [pinterest] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.pinterest.com/> from <POST https://www.pinterest.com/login/?next=%2Flogin%2F>
2013-09-28 19:17:09-0400 [pinterest] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.pinterest.com/join/discover/> from <GET http://www.pinterest.com/>
2013-09-28 19:17:10-0400 [pinterest] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.pinterest.com/join/discover/> (referer: https://www.pinterest.com/login/)
http://www.pinterest.com/join/discover/
```

Comment: It works! I didn't think to check if the field for the email changed so that's definitely something I learned to check for in the future. Thank you so much.